# In jquery, using .toggle method to show a text box based on the drop down list condition upsetting layout of page

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating a form for an asp.net application in which I need a text box to appear and the validator for it to become enabled based on a drop down list choice. I have gotten that all to work, but when the text box appears now, it is changing the layout of the other boxes around it. So it is functional, but not aesthetically pleasing at all. Unlike other questions similar to this on this site, my .toggle API must take the parameter of the condition. Just to be clear, I read my first jquery book last week, so I am by no means an expert. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my aspx page:

```
<div class="fieldContainer">
    <div class="dropDownValidate">
        <h3>Type of Burn:</h3>
        <span class="required" aria-required="true">(required)</span>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="typeOfBurnDropDownList" runat="server">

            <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Open (Example: Burning of brush and tree trimmings on residential property)" Value="O" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Agricultural  (Example: Removal of stubble from crops)" Value="A" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <div>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="typeOfBurnRequiredValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="typeOfBurnDropDownList" ErrorMessage="Type of Burn is required" ValidationGroup="validationGroup" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="True" />
            <div class="fieldContainer">
        <div id="acresContainer">
                <asp:Label ID="acresLabel" runat="server" Text="Number of acres to be burned:" AssociatedControlID="acresTextBox" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="acresTextBox" runat="server" Width="60px" MaxLength="8" />
                <span class="required" aria-required="true">(required)</span>
                <div>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="acresRequiredValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="acresTextBox" ErrorMessage="Number of acres to be burned is required" ValidationGroup="validationGroup" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="error" Enabled="false" />
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is my Jquery function.

```
$(function () {
$("[id$='_typeOfBurnDropDownList']").on("change", function () {
    var $requiredFieldValidator = $("[id$='acresRequiredValidator']"),
        condition = $(this).val() === "A",
        requiredFieldValidator = $requiredFieldValidator.get(0);
    requiredFieldValidator.enabled = condition;
    ValidatorUpdateDisplay(requiredFieldValidator)
    $('#acresContainer').toggle(condition);
});
```

Comment: yes, [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method changes the css display of the element to none and back, so when is none it will not use any "space" in the page, but when is back it will move things arround it.  You could put your element inside a div slightly bigger that holds it's position and allow it to toggle without moving things around.

Comment: Thank you! I feel very silly for not trying that first. It worked great!!